# Simulink and DLLs

Tags: c++, c, matlab, dll, simulink

I need to integrate a .EXE with simulink. I´m trying to do is create a C++ DLL in Simulink. This DLL should later be incorporated in a S-Function call in simulink.

The flow of information would be:

1. Simulink executes a S-function block
2. This block calls a method from C++ DLL
3. The C++ method executes a EXE, and return me a result
4. The result goes all the way back to simulink

ps: I dont have the source code of the EXE and it is a black box. That's why I am creating a c++ wrapper in order to execute it from simulink.

So far, the C++ DLL wrapper is not working. The code is below.

```
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus /* If this is a C++ compiler, use C linkage */
extern "C" {
#endif

namespace MathFuncs
{
    // This class is exported from the MathFuncsDll.dll
    class MyMathFuncs
    {
    public: 
        // Returns a + b
        static __declspec(dllexport)  double Add(double a, double b); 
    };
}

#ifdef __cplusplus /* If this is a C++ compiler, end C linkage */
}
#endif
```

*.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include "MathFuncsDll.h"
using namespace std;
namespace MathFuncs
{
    double MyMathFuncs::Add(double a, double b)
    {  return a + b;   }
}
```

Please notice that I´m using (extern "c") command in order to generate a DLL that can be used in Matlab C style.

When I try to load the DLL:

- loadlibrary('myDLL', 'myDLL.h')
- libfunctions MathFuncsDll

"No methods for class lib.MathFuncsDll or no class lib.MathFuncsDll."

So, my question is:

1. Whats wrong with my dll project?
2. Is it possible to integrate the exe with simulink using this approach?

obs: [Similar question here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45337-connecting-matlab-to-c-language-dll)

Comment: besides the c++ error: What is the purpos of the dll layer? I would run the exe from a matlab s function(`system`-command).

Comment: Well, is it possible? I didn't know. I will google it... Anyway, the DLL layer would be used to "translate" the simulink inputs to the EXE input. For example, all inputs for the EXE are text files. I would have to create new text file every simulation step

Comment: Why do you put this in a class? Doesn't that make life difficult for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give some tips:

You want a level 2 matlab s funcion, explained here: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html
Start with the `msfuntmpl_basic.m` template.

You can totally skip level 1 s functions, they only exist for backwards compartibility.

Answer (score 1):

I am not addressing the dll error, but your original problem of running the exe from Simulink.

1. Why not run the exe directly from MATALB code using `system` command like Daniel suggests?
2. If you write a C++ s-function, its interface is easier to implement and you can call your exe from the C++ s-function. i.e. Instead of your DLL you will use C++ s-function as the interface between Simulink and your exe.